# Line break in NSDateFormatter

Tags: nsdateformatter, line-breaks

I'm trying to create a line break between my date and time formats, but have not been successful. I've tried \n and \r with no success.

Thank you

Here is the code I have:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a";
NSDate *dateTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.selectedTransaction.createdAt];
```

Comment: What kind of strings are you using? Going the other way via `stringFromDate` works fine with `\n` in the format, and converting that string back via `dateFromString` also works.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the response, unforuntately I am not familiar enough objective C to answer your question. I was attempting to myself existing code on my app using google search + looking through the code. Thanks anyway

Comment: Any time you're using `NSDateFormatter` you need to know what the strings you're using look like. Here you're trying to convert `self.selectedTransaction.createdAt`, so you need to know what the string in that variable actually looks like. You can't possibly come up with a valid date format without a clear idea of what your date looks like.